# tf.train.get_checkpoint_state() return None

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a model.ckpt file that I downloaded from internet and located it in "ckpt" folder. When I have tried to get checkpoint it always return none. But when I check, the file is already exists. I'm a newbie in python. what's wrong with my code?

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    model_folder = "ckpt"
    if not tf.io.gfile.exists(model_folder):
        raise AssertionError(
        "Export directory doesn't exists. Please specify an export "
        "directory: %s" % model_folder)

    checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_folder)
    input_checkpoint = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading the checkpoint like [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load?hl=en):

```
import tensorflow as tf
model_folder = "ckpt"
latest = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_folder)
```

`get_checkpoint_state` does not get you the checkpoint, check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/get_checkpoint_state), it returns:

> A CheckpointState if the state was available, None otherwise.

Comment: it's still return none :(

Comment: Is the ckpt folder inside the directory you are executing che code from?

Comment: yes, it is. "ckpt" and executing code on the same folder

Comment: Umm probably you are missing other files. Do you have only the model.ckpt file inside the ckpt folder?

Comment: yes I have only. can I convert to model.pb with only model.ckpt file?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think you need the other files too in order to do that. Because .ckpt only holds the weights of the model, but has no information about the architecture.

Comment: can I convert PyTorch model.pt to apple mlmodel?